# XLINQ: string vs Convert.ToString() when extracting element values

Tags: xml, linq, casting, linq-to-xml, type-conversion

I am new to LINQ and using it to query XML (it's incredible). I have the following function which simply creates a new `List` object for each `list` descendant found in the XML.:

```
public void ParseLists(XDocument xDoc)
{
    XNamespace ns = xDoc.Root.Name.Namespace;
    AddRange((
        from e in xDoc.Descendants(ns + "list")
        select new List
        {
            Id = (string)e.Element(ns + "id"),
            ItemsLink = (string)e.Element(ns + "items-link"),
            BatchLink = (string)e.Element(ns + "batch-link"),
            Name = (string)e.Element(ns + "name"),
            IsVendor = (string)e.Element(ns + "is-vendor"),
            Levels = (string)e.Element(ns + "levels")
        }).ToList());
}
```

And here's a snippet of what the XML might look like:

```
<lists xmlns="www.namespaceurl.com" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <list>
    <batch-link>www.batchlinkurl.com</batch-link>
    <id>12345</id>
    . . .
  </list>
</lists>
```

**The Question**: When building the `List` objects, I initially used `Convert.ToString()` rather than `(string)` to get the elements values as a string. What I found was that:

`Convert.ToString(e.Element(ns + "id"))` will return `<id>12345</id>`

whereas

`(string)e.Element(ns + "id")` will return `12345`.

**Can someone explain why the return value is different?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Convert.ToString(...)` will call the overridden [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341005.aspx) method, which returns the *element itself* as a string.

`(string) ...` will use the [overloaded explicit conversion to string operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155263), which returns the *text contents* of the element as a string.

Comment: And it's as simple as that. Thanks Jon!